# Laravel (5.2) Excel download xls error ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE (chrome)

Tags: php, excel, laravel-5

I can't download/export in `xls` or `xlsx` , only in `csv` format

```
$data = Orders::get();
$xls = Excel::create('Orders', function($excel) use($data) {

          $excel->sheet('orders', function($sheet) use($data) {

              $sheet->fromArray($data);

          });

      })->download('xls');
return redirect()->back();
```

I tried to ob_clean in the laravelexcelwriter.php on method _download(line 317) , above the save function(line 341), no result. Also in the save function(line 341) I tried similar options for I/O streams (default is `php://output`) like `php://stdout`, `php://stderr`, `php://fd`, `php://memory` and still no result.

is this a php.ini problem? a server problem ? where should I check ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you got the error on Google Chrome Browser, which is the same error as I made.
Have you installed php ziparchive module?
Please try to install that. If you are in php 7, then following might help you.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip
```

Thanks

Comment: Enabling the PHP zip module fixed this issue for me. Was missing it from the dev docker container but was enabled on production and had me puzzled for a minute. If you're using the official PHP docker images you can `docker-php-ext-install zip` in your dockerfile to build it with zip.

Answer (score 0):

Editing the time limit and memory limit fixed it for me. Try what happens if you put this before the Excel::create() method:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '1G');
```